# Исключение NullReferenceException EntityFrameworkCore (7.0.1)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Только начинаю изучать ASP.NET и EntityFrameworkCore, и у меня возникли проблемы со связями между таблицами.
Хочу вивести таблицу `Transactions`, с полем `Categories.Name` и `OperationTypes.Type`  и получаю `NullReferenceException`.  Не могу понять в чем дело. Таблицу `Categories` выводит без проблем.

Файл Categories.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace TryCreateDB.Models
{
    public class Categories
    {
        public Categories()
        {
            this.Transactions = new HashSet<Transactions>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Transactions> Transactions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Файл OperationTypes.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace TryCreateDB.Models
{
    public class OperationTypes
    {
        public OperationTypes()
        {
            this.Transactions = new HashSet<Transactions>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int TypeId { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Transactions> Transactions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Файл Transactions.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace TryCreateDB.Models
{
    public class Transactions
    {
        [Key]
        public int TransactionId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int TypeId { get; set; }
        public double Amount { get; set; }
        public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
        public virtual Categories Categories { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("TypeId")]
        public virtual OperationTypes OperationTypes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Файл ApplicationContext.cs

```
using TryCreateDB.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace TryCreateDB.Data
{
    public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options): base(options) {
        }
        public DbSet<Categories> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OperationTypes> OperationTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Transactions> Transactions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Файл TransactionsController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TryCreateDB.Data;
namespace TryCreateDB.Controllers
{
    public class TransactionsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationContext _context;
        public TransactionsController(ApplicationContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Transactions.ToListAsync());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Загрузка связанных данных. Метод Include](https://metanit.com/sharp/efcore/3.3.php)

Comment: @tym32167, да сработало. Извините что так долго не был в сети. А можно как-то обойтись без Include, я видел решения с использованием метода OnModelCreating в класе ApplicationContext, но не понимаю как реализовать под свои модельки.

Comment: вам нужно грузить связанные таблицы, это способ как их грузить. Вы можете пробовать как то по другому пытаться это делать, но это будет стрельбой по ногам себе. Есть какая то причина, почему вы не хотите include использовать?